# Xamarin-Forms Fast Renderers not works

Tags: xamarin.forms, renderer

Im using **Fast-Renderer** in my Xamarin-App.

However, Fast Rendering doesn't work with Custom Renders.

Someone can help me understand why it works only with normal Xamarin-Forms Controls, but doesn't work with custom Renders Controls?

Comment: grammar and typo fixes.

Comment: "Doesn't work" - what happens:  Can't build?  Crashes when run?  Isn't any faster?

Comment: It's building properly, but not effecting for Custom Renders, only works for Xamarin-Controls. Im using Xamarin-Inspector also for seeing reduced controls layout but Fast Renderer reduces control layout for Xamarin  Controls only.